# no 'edit' option for Q&A at Programmers meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I noticed there's no 'edit' option for questions and answers posted at Programmers meta - as opposed to eg Programmers, SO and So meta.

Is that intentional? a missing feature? something else?

- example of 'edit' option as it looks at SO meta:
  [image: screen shot]

  **update** *SO meta* turns out to be a special case, as explained in [answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2179/no-edit-option-for-qa-at-programmers-meta/2180#2180)
- example of how this looks to me at programmers meta:
  [image: screen shot]

  there's *retag* link placed where I would expect *edit*

Note To avoid misunderstanding, I refer to 'edit' option for Q&A posted by other members (for my own posts it appears ok)

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of what you are seeing here?

Comment: @ChrisF done - please take a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Suggested edits are disabled on meta sites, so you will need to have 2,000 reputation before you will see the edit link on other people's posts. The only exception is Meta Stack Exchange which functions as a meta for all Stack Exchange sites and has its own reputation pool.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87890/why-cant-i-suggest-edits-on-se-meta-sites/97371#97371) for Jeff Atwood's explanation of the rationale behind that decision.

Comment: for the sake of completeness - please note suggested edits appear to be enabled at _SO meta_: screen shot with green marks is taken from it. Anyway, explanation of _status-bydesign_ makes good sense to me

Comment: @gnat Yeah, Meta SO is a special case.

Comment: MSO is a meta site, but it is different from the other meta sites because it started as an independent site; for example, on MSO you have a reputation, while on other meta sites the reputation that is shown is the reputation you have on the main site. (See this very meta site as example.)